# 1054 Unknown column 'extra_query'

Tags: joomla-3.x, sql

I have a new Joomla installation with this error:

```
1054 Unknown column 'extra_query' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT DISTINCT update_site_id, type, location, last_check_timestamp, extra_query FROM no3a2_update_sites WHERE enabled = 1
```

The error is displayed when I want to open my template settings. The template is from RocketTheme.

What can I do?

Comment: Joomla Forum Thread: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=834705

Answer (score 4):

You give very little information to give a good answer, but there are a couple of things you can try:

- Make sure both Joomla and your template is up to date
- Re-upload your template if possible
- Fix your database by going to Extension manager -> Database, and click the `Fix` button in the upper left corner

[image: Fix Database]

Comment: can anyone tell me from which joomla version "extra_query" column added to the core table update_sites ?

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

> 1054 Unknown column 'a.extra_query' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT DISTINCT a.update_site_id, a.type, a.location, a.last_check_timestamp, a.extra_query FROM #__update_sites AS a INNER JOIN #__update_sites_extensions AS b ON a.update_site_id = b.update_site_id WHERE a.enabled = 1 AND b.extension_id IN (700)

The error (or similar errors) shows that in `#__update_sites` table in your database the column named `extra_query` is missing, thus the query cannot be executed. The easiest way to handle this error is creating an `extra_query` column in that table. You can do that via **phpMyAdmin** area on your server account. There are a lot of easy instructions of how to do that, I just link one here:

https://www.pair.com/support/kb/adding-a-column-to-a-database-in-phpmyadmin/

The field type might be set to `TEXT` type (it could be VARCHAR or other type but TEXT is OK and later can be changed).

Maybe the earlier suggested **fix database** button pushing is even simpler solution in Joomla admin. The reason I’m giving the above as the answer is that I many times have seen this issue happened with other database table fields too during bigger upgrades, not only Joomla core table fields, and those might not be fixed within Joomla admin.

During the upgrade of Joomla sites there probably will be few similar issues (and probably some worse than this issue). So maybe it is better to turn on development mode in global configuration of your Joomla to see the full stack of errors if/when those happen...

Answer (score -2):

The error is saying that your no3a2_update_sites table don't contain any column named extra_query which might be used some where in your template.You can either create that column in your database to temporarily avoid it or try reinstalling the template.